# Android: Simplest way to calculate delta of touch position?

Tags: android, touch, touch-event

I want to calculate the delta of touch positions on the screen. For that, I'm using this code:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    touchX = (int) event.getX();
    touchY = (int) event.getY();

    deltaX = touchX - oldX;
    deltaY = touchY - oldY;

    oldX = touchX;
    oldY = touchY;

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Now, when I move the finger on screen for some time, I get the correct delta. But the problem occurs when I stop my finger, but don't lift it. At that time, I just get the non-zero delta of last frame. It is because `onTouchEvent` is not called when the finger is on screen but static. I should get zero delta when finger is static.

What's the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finger remaining stopped on the screen is **not** a `MotionEvent`, so this method will not be called.

Try this.

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private static final int FINGER_STOP_THRESHOLD = 500;

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    touchX = (int) event.getX();
    touchY = (int) event.getY();

    deltaX = touchX - oldX;
    deltaY = touchY - oldY;

    oldX = touchX;
    oldY = touchY;

    mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    if(event.getActionMasked() != MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                deltaX = 0;
                deltaY = 0;
            }
        }, FINGER_STOP_THRESHOLD);
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

You may change the `FINGER_STOP_THRESHOLD` to the value you want.

Comment: I was using the same method before except the line `mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);`. But it was kind of laggy. Using your solution has killed the lag. What does this line do?

Comment: This line removes all pending tasks. It is necessary because if a new touch event occurs, all previous waiting make no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, everything is commented on the code :

```
 Double x;//Using double, so I can assign null to this, when touch is removed
    Double y;
    
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        int action = motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            x=Double.valueOf(motionEvent.getX());//On touch, set initial position
            y=Double.valueOf(motionEvent.getY());
        }
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            x= null;//On touch removed, set it to null
            y=null;
        }
       
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            Log.d("d--diff", (x-motionEvent.getX()) + " - " + (y-motionEvent.getY()));
            //Calculate difference
        }
        return true;
    }
```

If you have any query, feel free to ask.